# Consumer doesn't get message from topics created after subscription

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have create some KafkaConsumer, next call subscribe on it (using Pattern), and next poll.
I noticed that if my consumer running, and later I create some new topic (matches to pattern) this consument will not consume this data! If I restart my app then consumer get data from newly created topics.
It is ok ? How can I solve it ?

Comment: Yes. thanks a lot. After reading that topic i have two doubts: I dont understand why someone suggest seting seekToBeginning and I think about costs of decreasing this value - I set it to 1s.

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand the comment you are reffering to and to be honest also not your comment :) If you have a new question it might be more efficient to start a new question on Stackoverflow instead of dicussing a comment from another answer in this question.

Comment: Or even better: Ask your question directly under the comment you are unclear. I know you do not have enough reputation to comment, but you will get there soon!

Comment: Ok, no matter about that. As I understand it is important to change matadata.max.age.ms and set auto.offset.reset to earliest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The KafkaConsumer will do a refresh of meta data of its subscriptions based on the KafkaConsumer configuration `metadata.max.age.ms` which defaults to 5 minutes.

You could reduce this configuration to have your consumer consuming also newly created topics matching your pattern.